# How to avoid collapse menubar and cover carousel in website?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

first of all im sorry for taking your time. I used album cover slider and superfish in my first site and they collapsed. I can use slider perfectly but i cant use my menu. Submenus and everything shows when i take my cursor to there. I want to learn how to avoid click collapse in js projects, little explanation would help me big time.

Here are the JS's.

for menu

```
 * jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.9
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

;(function ($, w) {
    "use strict";

    var methods = (function () {
        // private properties and methods go here
        var c = {
                bcClass: 'sf-breadcrumb',
                menuClass: 'sf-js-enabled',
                anchorClass: 'sf-with-ul',
                menuArrowClass: 'sf-arrows'
            },
            ios = (function () {
                var ios = /^(?![\w\W]*Windows Phone)[\w\W]*(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                if (ios) {
                    // tap anywhere on iOS to unfocus a submenu
                    $('html').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', $.noop);
                }
                return ios;
            })(),
            wp7 = (function () {
                var style = document.documentElement.style;
                return ('behavior' in style && 'fill' in style && /iemobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
            })(),
            unprefixedPointerEvents = (function () {
                return (!!w.PointerEvent);
            })(),
            toggleMenuClasses = function ($menu, o, add) {
                var classes = c.menuClass,
                    method;
                if (o.cssArrows) {
                    classes += ' ' + c.menuArrowClass;
                }
                method = (add) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
                $menu[method](classes);
            },
            setPathToCurrent = function ($menu, o) {
                return $menu.find('li.' + o.pathClass).slice(0, o.pathLevels)
                    .addClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass)
                        .filter(function () {
                            return ($(this).children(o.popUpSelector).hide().show().length);
                        }).removeClass(o.pathClass);
            },
            toggleAnchorClass = function ($li, add) {
                var method = (add) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
                $li.children('a')[method](c.anchorClass);
            },
            toggleTouchAction = function ($menu) {
                var msTouchAction = $menu.css('ms-touch-action');
                var touchAction = $menu.css('touch-action');
                touchAction = touchAction || msTouchAction;
                touchAction = (touchAction === 'pan-y') ? 'auto' : 'pan-y';
                $menu.css({
                    'ms-touch-action': touchAction,
                    'touch-action': touchAction
                });
            },
            getMenu = function ($el) {
                return $el.closest('.' + c.menuClass);
            },
            getOptions = function ($el) {
                return getMenu($el).data('sfOptions');
            },
            over = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                $this.siblings().superfish('hide').end().superfish('show');
            },
            close = function (o) {
                o.retainPath = ($.inArray(this[0], o.$path) > -1);
                this.superfish('hide');

                if (!this.parents('.' + o.hoverClass).length) {
                    o.onIdle.call(getMenu(this));
                    if (o.$path.length) {
                        $.proxy(over, o.$path)();
                    }
                }
            },
            out = function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                if (ios) {
                    $.proxy(close, $this, o)();
                }
                else {
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    o.sfTimer = setTimeout($.proxy(close, $this, o), o.delay);
                }
            },
            touchHandler = function (e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this),
                    $ul = $this.siblings(e.data.popUpSelector);

                if (o.onHandleTouch.call($ul) === false) {
                    return this;
                }

                if ($ul.length > 0 && $ul.is(':hidden')) {
                    $this.one('click.superfish', false);
                    if (e.type === 'MSPointerDown' || e.type === 'pointerdown') {
                        $this.trigger('focus');
                    } else {
                        $.proxy(over, $this.parent('li'))();
                    }
                }
            },
            applyHandlers = function ($menu, o) {
                var targets = 'li:has(' + o.popUpSelector + ')';
                if ($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) {
                    $menu.hoverIntent(over, out, targets);
                }
                else {
                    $menu
                        .on('mouseenter.superfish', targets, over)
                        .on('mouseleave.superfish', targets, out);
                }
                var touchevent = 'MSPointerDown.superfish';
                if (unprefixedPointerEvents) {
                    touchevent = 'pointerdown.superfish';
                }
                if (!ios) {
                    touchevent += ' touchend.superfish';
                }
                if (wp7) {
                    touchevent += ' mousedown.superfish';
                }
                $menu
                    .on('focusin.superfish', 'li', over)
                    .on('focusout.superfish', 'li', out)
                    .on(touchevent, 'a', o, touchHandler);
            };

        return {
            // public methods
            hide: function (instant) {
                if (this.length) {
                    var $this = this,
                        o = getOptions($this);
                    if (!o) {
                        return this;
                    }
                    var not = (o.retainPath === true) ? o.$path : '',
                        $ul = $this.find('li.' + o.hoverClass).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass).children(o.popUpSelector),
                        speed = o.speedOut;

                    if (instant) {
                        $ul.show();
                        speed = 0;
                    }
                    o.retainPath = false;

                    if (o.onBeforeHide.call($ul) === false) {
                        return this;
                    }

                    $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        o.onHide.call($this);
                    });
                }
                return this;
            },
            show: function () {
                var o = getOptions(this);
                if (!o) {
                    return this;
                }
                var $this = this.addClass(o.hoverClass),
                    $ul = $this.children(o.popUpSelector);

                if (o.onBeforeShow.call($ul) === false) {
                    return this;
                }

                $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animation, o.speed, function () {
                    o.onShow.call($ul);
                });
                return this;
            },
            destroy: function () {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        o = $this.data('sfOptions'),
                        $hasPopUp;
                    if (!o) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    // remove event handlers
                    $this.off('.superfish').off('.hoverIntent');
                    // clear animation's inline display style
                    $hasPopUp.children(o.popUpSelector).attr('style', function (i, style) {
                        return style.replace(/display[^;]+;?/g, '');
                    });
                    // reset 'current' path classes
                    o.$path.removeClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass).addClass(o.pathClass);
                    $this.find('.' + o.hoverClass).removeClass(o.hoverClass);
                    o.onDestroy.call($this);
                    $this.removeData('sfOptions');
                });
            },
            init: function (op) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('sfOptions')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.superfish.defaults, op),
                        $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    o.$path = setPathToCurrent($this, o);

                    $this.data('sfOptions', o);

                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o, true);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp, true);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    applyHandlers($this, o);

                    $hasPopUp.not('.' + c.bcClass).superfish('hide', true);

                    o.onInit.call(this);
                });
            }
        };
    })();

    $.fn.superfish = function (method, args) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else {
            return $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fn.superfish');
        }
    };

    $.fn.superfish.defaults = {
        popUpSelector: 'ul,.sf-mega', // within menu context
        hoverClass: 'sfHover',
        pathClass: 'overrideThisToUse',
        pathLevels: 1,
        delay: 800,
        animation: {opacity: 'show'},
        animationOut: {opacity: 'hide'},
        speed: 'normal',
        speedOut: 'fast',
        cssArrows: true,
        disableHI: false,
        onInit: $.noop,
        onBeforeShow: $.noop,
        onShow: $.noop,
        onBeforeHide: $.noop,
        onHide: $.noop,
        onIdle: $.noop,
        onDestroy: $.noop,
        onHandleTouch: $.noop
    };

})(jQuery, window);
```

````
 Album Cover Slider
 --------------------------------*/
//start added by Chase
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var cfImg = document.getElementsByClassName("coverflow__image")

var scaleI = 0;
for (scaleI; scaleI < a.length; scaleI++) {
    if (scaleI === 3) {
        continue;
    } else {
        a[scaleI].style.cursor = "default";
        a[scaleI].addEventListener("click", prevDef);
    }
}

function prevDef(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function forScale(coverflowPos) {
    for (scaleI = 0; scaleI < a.length; scaleI++) {
        a[scaleI].style.cursor = "default";
        a[scaleI].addEventListener("click", prevDef);
    }
    for (scaleI = 0; scaleI < cfImg.length; scaleI++) {
        if (cfImg[scaleI].getAttribute("data-coverflow-index") == coverflowPos) {
            cfImg[scaleI].parentElement.style.cursor = "pointer";
            cfImg[scaleI].parentElement.removeEventListener("click", prevDef);
        }
    }
}
//end added by Chase

function setupCoverflow(coverflowContainer) {
    var coverflowContainers;

    if (typeof coverflowContainer !== "undefined") {
        if (Array.isArray(coverflowContainer)) {
            coverflowContainers = coverflowContainer;
        } else {
            coverflowContainers = [coverflowContainer];
        }
    } else {
        coverflowContainers = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName('coverflow'));
    }

    coverflowContainers.forEach(function(containerElement) {
        var coverflow = {};
        var prevArrows, nextArrows;

        //capture coverflow elements
        coverflow.container = containerElement;
        coverflow.images = Array.prototype.slice.apply(containerElement.getElementsByClassName('coverflow__image'));
        coverflow.position = Math.floor(coverflow.images.length / 2) + 1;

        //set indicies on images
        coverflow.images.forEach(function(coverflowImage, i) {
            coverflowImage.dataset.coverflowIndex = i + 1;
        });

        //set initial position
        coverflow.container.dataset.coverflowPosition = coverflow.position;

        //get prev/next arrows
        prevArrows = Array.prototype.slice.apply(coverflow.container.getElementsByClassName("prev-arrow"));
        nextArrows = Array.prototype.slice.apply(coverflow.container.getElementsByClassName("next-arrow"));

        //add event handlers
        function setPrevImage() {
            coverflow.position = Math.max(1, coverflow.position - 1);
            coverflow.container.dataset.coverflowPosition = coverflow.position;
            //call the functin forScale added
            forScale(coverflow.position);
        }

        function setNextImage() {
            coverflow.position = Math.min(coverflow.images.length, coverflow.position + 1);
            coverflow.container.dataset.coverflowPosition = coverflow.position;
            //call the function Chase added
            forScale(coverflow.position);
        }

        function jumpToImage(evt) {
            coverflow.position = Math.min(coverflow.images.length, Math.max(1, evt.target.dataset.coverflowIndex));
            coverflow.container.dataset.coverflowPosition = coverflow.position;
            //start added by Chase
            setTimeout(function() {
                forScale(coverflow.position);
            }, 1);
            //end added by Chase
        }

        function onKeyPress(evt) {
            switch (evt.which) {
                case 37: //left arrow
                    setPrevImage();
                    break;
                case 39: //right arrow
                    setNextImage();
                    break;
            }
        }
        prevArrows.forEach(function(prevArrow) {
            prevArrow.addEventListener('click', setPrevImage);
        });
        nextArrows.forEach(function(nextArrow) {
            nextArrow.addEventListener('click', setNextImage);
        });
        coverflow.images.forEach(function(image) {
            image.addEventListener('click', jumpToImage);
        });
        window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyPress);
    });
}

setupCoverflow(); ```
````